# How to scale multiple tikz images so they appear the same size

Tags: tikz-pgf

Given the three images

Img1:

```
\documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,%
    positioning,%
    shapes}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance = 1cm, thick,
        every node/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw, text width = 2cm, black, align = center, minimum height = 1cm}]
        
        \node (MD) {Managing Directors};
        
        \node[below=of MD] (Design) {Design};
        \node[left=of Design] (Project) {Project};
        \node[left=of Project] (Sales) {Sales};
        \node[right=of Design] (Production) {Production};
        \node[right=of Production] (Service) {Service};
        
        \draw (MD) -- (Design);
        
        \coordinate[below  = 0.5cm of MD] (Connection);
        
        \draw (Connection) -| (Sales);
        
        \draw (Connection) -| (Service);
        
        \coordinate[above  = 0.5cm of Project] (ConnectionProject);
        
        \draw (ConnectionProject) -- (Project);
        
        \coordinate[above  = 0.5cm of Production] (ConnectionProduction);
        
        \draw (ConnectionProduction) -- (Production);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Img2:

```
\documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,%
    positioning,%
    shapes}
\tikzset{%
    Block/.style ={rectangle, rounded corners, draw, text width = 2cm, align = center, minimum height = 1cm}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance = 1cm, thick]
        
        \node[Block] (MD) {Managing Directors};
        
        \node[Block, below=of MD] (Project) {Project};
        
        \node[Block, below=of Project] (IT) {IT};
        
        \draw[-latex'] (Project) -- (MD);
        
        \draw[dashed] (Project) -- (IT);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

and Img3:

```
\documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,%
    positioning,%
    shapes}
\tikzset{%
    Block/.style ={rectangle, rounded corners, draw, text width = 2.5cm, align = center, minimum height = 1.5cm}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance = 1cm, thick]
        
        \node[Block] (KP) {process};
        
        \node[Block, below=of KP] (VA) {sales};
        
        \node[Block, below left=of VA] (EL) {delivery};
        
        \node[Block, below right=of VA] (UeL) {examination};
        
        \draw[-latex'] (KP) -- (VA);
        
        \coordinate[below=0.25cm of VA] (Connection);
        
        \draw (VA) -- (Connection);
        
        \draw[-latex'] (Connection) -| (EL);
        
        \draw[-latex'] (Connection) -| (UeL);
        
        \draw[-latex'] (EL) -- (UeL) node [midway, above] {manual};
        
        \coordinate[below=3cm of VA] (Connection2);
        
        \draw[dashed, -latex'] (EL) |- (Connection2) -| (UeL);
        
        \node[below=3cm of VA, above] (digital) {digital};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

How can I add them to a document so that they appear the same size (the size that is the same in all nodes across all three images is the node width), as I can't have them all in their native size, because Img1 is too wide and needs to be scaled down:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Img1.pdf}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics{Img2.pdf}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics{Img3.pdf}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Is there e.g. any possibility to get to know the scaling factor of Img1 and use it to scale Img2 and Img3 respectively?

Comment: Is [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458511/how-to-scale-multiple-elements-to-maximum-width-while-keeping-their-relative-siz) useful? By the way, the first two of your images do not compile and my German is still awful...

Comment: Thanks for the information, I edited the post, all images should now be compilable and I replaced the German phrases with English ones. Regarding your link: I will have a look into it, but it seems to be promising at first glance!